# Difference between mysql and sql server? Performance, features,...?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

What are the differences between MySQL and Sql server?
What are the parameter to chose between the two?

Comment: Lots of differences. Do you have any particular requirements?

Comment: You'll need to narrow your difference scope down. Cost? Performance? Scalability? Maintenance? etc...

Answer (score 4):

Several questions here related to DB comparisons of various flavors:

[What are the major differences between databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481879/what-are-the-major-differences-between-databases)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/why-isnt-postgresql-as-widespread-as-mysql

[Where to find a good reference when choosing a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195353/where-to-find-a-good-reference-when-choosing-a-database)

[postgresSQL mysql oracle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216601/postgressql-mysql-oracle-diferences)

Answer (score 2):

The paramater to choose between the two is the price tag. How much do you "expect" to pay for your database. If its zero then MySQL is probably good enough for you, if its 10k then SQL Server is probably good enough for you.

As for the actual differences, there are too many to list.